# webkit-playsinline is not working

Tags: html, iframe, hybrid

I'm making a hybrid app that requires a video to be played on the page, and not in the native fullscreen video player on an iPhone.  I have tried `webkit-playsinline` in an iframe with the YouTube API, but it is not working.  Heres the iframe code:

```html
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/morestuffhere"
  frameborder="0" webkit-playsinline></iframe>
```

I also put his in my viewDidLoad for Swift:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

But the native player shows up no matter what.  What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: On iPad? Since on iPhone it's always full screen regardless of attributes. And I think the attribute should be on the video element, iframe has no concept of playing video.

Comment: I was trying to make it play inline on iPhones, i'll update the post to say that.

Comment: Is there any way possible I can work around it?  The app relies on it playing inline, and I'm really stuck.

Comment: Sorry, on a normal website only iPad shows inline, but with embedded webview it should be possible on iPhone also. So the issue is the attribute placement

Comment: So your saying it is possible?  Maybe it wasn't working because I put the webkit-playsinline in an iframe and not a video tag.  The only problem is, I cant get a video tag because of Youtube's API deprecating it.

Answer (score 0):

The inline attribute should be placed on the video element, not on the iframe element. If you use the iframe method you cannot enable the inline playback this way since the actual video element won't have the required attribute.

Comment: Ok thank you! You've saved me hours looking this up on Google!

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/morestuffhere&playsinline=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Also put webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true in viewDidLoad for Swift